# Calling a function from another python script with a while loop

Tags: python

I have a python script with a function and a while loop and I want to call this function from another python script which also has a while loop. Here is an example script:

script1.py:

```
global printline
printline = abc

def change(x):
    global printline
    printline = x

while True:
    global printline
    print printline
```

And this is script2.py:

```
from script1 import change

change(xyz)

while True:
    print hello
```

When I run script2.py, it starts to print abc and doesn't go into the while loop in this script.

When I run script1.py, it prints abc.

When I run both together, in different terminals, both print abc.

I need it so that when both scripts are run, script2.py can change the variable printline while going into the while loop.

I don't know if this is the right way to do it as I'm new to python.

Thanks.

Comment: Those can't possibly be your actual scripts. Wouldn't you get "name is not defined" errors on `abc` and `xyz`? Please post the actual code you are having trouble with, verbatim, otherwise all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: Are these scripts supposed to be separate programs that share the same `printline` variable? As in, when both scripts run at the same time, they share the same `printline` variable?

Comment: Are `abc` and `xyz` supposed to be strings `"abc"` and `"xyz"`?

Comment: There's no point in putting a `global` statement outside a function.

Comment: When you import from a file, all the statements that aren't in functions are executed normally, just as if you ran the script by itself. So the `while True:` code in `script1.py` executes, and it never gets out of that infinite loop. Top-level statements in a module file are just expected to initialize the module, they need to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `from script1 import change`, it executes all the top-level code in `script1.py`. So it executes the `while True:` block, which loops infinitely, and it never returns back to `script2.py`.

You need to split up `script1.py` so that you can import the `change()` function without executing the top-level code.

change.py:

```
def change(x):
    global printline
    printline = x
```

script1.py:

```
from change import change

change("abc")
while True:
    print printline
```

script2.py:

```
from change import change

change("xyz");
while True:
    print printline
```